# unable to load template file using spring and tile integration

Tags: templates, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

I am new to Apache tiles, trying to configure it in spring 4. But the templates, i am extending is not visible in my jsp page.For ex: If i am hitting url "/admin", then content of admin.jsp is visible, nothing else.
blow is the code snippet.

**application-context.xml**

```
<beans:bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver" />

    <beans:bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="definitions">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>/WEB-INF/layouts/views.xml</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
```

**views.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC  
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN"  
        "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>

 <definition name="DefaultTemplate" 
      template="/WEB-INF/views/template/SiteTemplate.jsp">
<put-attribute name="title" value="Home" />
<put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/template/header.jsp" />
<put-attribute name="body" value="This is body" />
<put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/template/footer.jsp" />
</definition>
<definition name="admin" extends="DefaultTemplate">
    <put-attribute name="body"
        value="/WEB-INF/views/admin.jsp" />
</definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

**SiteTemplate.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>DCAT</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<!-- Header -->
<tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
<!-- Body Page -->
<div>
<tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
</div>
<!-- Footer Page -->
<tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Footer.jsp**

```
<div>
    <h2>Footer</h2>
</div>
```

**Header.jsp**

```
<div>
    <h2>Header</h2>
</div>
```

**admin.jsp**

```
<div style="margin:10px;">
<h3>SpringMVC - Tiles3 Integration</h3>
<p>By:- Thita Nayak</p>
</div>
```

**Admin controller**

```
@Controller
public class AdminController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AdminController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String admin(){

        return "admin";

    }
}
```

Comment: can you please share the namespace of your views.xml

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see anything wrong with your code 
The problem might be in the namespace declaration

Try to change beans:bean to beans if your namespace is as follow

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" ...
```

Comment: Thanks Quentin for your response, some jar files were not included in pom.xml. Now it's working fine.....